# CRM for Outlook Connector - failure to initialize after AD password reset

Tags: outlook-addin, dynamics-crm-2011

Everything seems to work fine with my dynamics CRM 2011 until the day when there is an auto password request from our AD. I have the crm for outlook connector and this does not get initialized after I change the AD password - just a plain old outlook with mail and everything comes up, but no crm.

how do I resolve this? more importantly whats the long term solution? because our AD password reset occurs every 2months....ouch!

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager in section Generic Credentials delete the correspondent entry for your crm.